# After reinstalling VS 2022 professional, my project compilation returns warning C4566

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2022

I previously created a project using Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 LTSC and used Open CV. The project could be compiled successfully. Later, I reinstalled Visual Studio Professional 2022 LTSC. When I opened the project again for compilation, there was a compilation error in the Open CV code:

```
Warning C4566   character represented by universal-character-name '\u2161' cannot be represented in the current code page (1252)    Compute opencv2\core\matx.hpp   695
```

I didn’t make any changes to my project. Did some settings change that caused these problems? How should I set it up so that my project can be compiled successfully?

When I first opened the project, there was a prompt, which seemed to be about choosing which encoding to use to open the file (I don’t remember, I didn’t pay attention to the prompt at the time, and directly chose No). I suspect that VS has been using the default encoding to open files since then, instead of using the file’s own encoding UTF-8. But I don’t know how to reset this option. I reinstalled Visual Studio Professional 2022 LTSC, but the option box did not pop up again.